# Change href on modal event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the `href` of the link in the modal using the `id` of the clicked link. Though using `prop` works fine in the  console it doesn't seem to work in my snippet. I don't know what i'm doing wrong...

My link:

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  id="1" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>
```

My script :

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var $modal = $(this),
  myId ='home.php?menu=15&status=delete&id=' + e.relatedTarget.id;
  $modal.prop('href',myId);
})
```

My Modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">........</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body edit-content">
        <p><strong>..........</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="home.php?menu=15&status=delete&id=5" id="modalLink" class="btn btn-default" >yes</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary "data-dismiss="modal">no</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `attr('href', myId)`?

Comment: yes , same result works in console not in my code though

Comment: Are you sure `show.bs.modal` is fired? Maybe you try to bind it before element `#myModal` is available in DOM

Comment: it is fired, i added  $modal.find('.edit-content').html(myId) to the script and it the content changed, the href remained the same....

Comment: No error in console? Are you sure `e.relatedTarget` is defined? It more looks like you want `e.target.id` even i have no clue what is your expected behaviour

Comment: No errors. it is defined when i use  $modal.find('.edit-content').html(myID) it returns me the variable value in the modal.

Comment: But if you check after setting href prop using  `console.log($modal.prop('href'));`, is it returning expected result? BTW, i still don't know what is your expected behaviour. A jsFiddle would help for sure

Comment: ok that was it, $modal was not defined correcty, i didnt pass the element to a variable and it worked correctly! Thank you very much for guiding me! How can i vote up for you in comments?